# Http response code 500 when accessing paypal payment

Tags: php, paypal

When create a payment using PAYPAL I get this Exception:

```
                            PayPal\Exception\PayPalConnectionException

                            File:

                                /var/www/clients/client2/web93/web/vendor/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/lib/PayPal/Core/PayPalHttpConnection.php:178

                            Message:

                                Got Http response code 500 when accessing https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/payments/payment.

                            Stack trace:

                                #0 /var/www/clients/client2/web93/web/vendor/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/lib/PayPal/Transport/PayPalRestCall.php(74): PayPal\Core\PayPalHttpConnection->execute('{"intent":"sale...')
                                #1 /var/www/clients/client2/web93/web/vendor/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/lib/PayPal/Common/PayPalResourceModel.php(102): PayPal\Transport\PayPalRestCall->execute(Array, '/v1/payments/pa...', 'POST', '{"intent":"sale...', NULL)
                                #2 /var/www/clients/client2/web93/web/vendor/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/lib/PayPal/Api/Payment.php(579): PayPal\Common\PayPalResourceModel::executeCall('/v1/payments/pa...', 'POST', '{"intent":"sale...', NULL, Object(PayPal\Rest\ApiContext), NULL)
                                #3 /var/www/clients/client2/web93/web/module/Application/src/Application/Controller/CompanyController.php(399): PayPal\Api\Payment->create(Object(PayPal\Rest\ApiContext))
```

and this is the request I"m sending to paypal sdk:

```
                            object(PayPal\Api\Payment)#1045 (1) {
                              ["_propMap":"PayPal\Common\PayPalModel":private]=>
                              array(4) {
                                ["intent"]=>
                                string(4) "sale"
                                ["payer"]=>
                                object(PayPal\Api\Payer)#1039 (1) {
                                  ["_propMap":"PayPal\Common\PayPalModel":private]=>
                                  array(1) {
                                    ["payment_method"]=>
                                    string(6) "payapl"
                                  }
                                }
                                ["redirect_urls"]=>
                                object(PayPal\Api\RedirectUrls)#1044 (1) {
                                  ["_propMap":"PayPal\Common\PayPalModel":private]=>
                                  array(2) {
                                    ["return_url"]=>
                                    string(17) "http://google.com"
                                    ["cancel_url"]=>
                                    string(17) "http://google.com"
                                  }
                                }
                                ["transactions"]=>
                                array(1) {
                                  [0]=>
                                  object(PayPal\Api\Transaction)#1043 (1) {
                                    ["_propMap":"PayPal\Common\PayPalModel":private]=>
                                    array(4) {
                                      ["amount"]=>
                                      object(PayPal\Api\Amount)#1041 (1) {
                                        ["_propMap":"PayPal\Common\PayPalModel":private]=>
                                        array(2) {
                                          ["currency"]=>
                                          string(3) "USD"
                                          ["total"]=>
                                          string(2) "95"
                                        }
                                      }
                                      ["item_list"]=>
                                      object(PayPal\Api\ItemList)#1036 (1) {
                                        ["_propMap":"PayPal\Common\PayPalModel":private]=>
                                        array(1) {
                                          ["items"]=>
                                          array(1) {
                                            [0]=>
                                            object(PayPal\Api\Item)#1035 (1) {
                                              ["_propMap":"PayPal\Common\PayPalModel":private]=>
                                              array(4) {
                                                ["name"]=>
                                                string(9) "e-toolset"
                                                ["currency"]=>
                                                string(3) "USD"
                                                ["quantity"]=>
                                                int(1)
                                                ["price"]=>
                                                string(2) "95"
                                              }
                                            }
                                          }
                                        }
                                      }
                                      ["description"]=>
                                      string(17) "E-Toolset package"
                                      ["invoice_number"]=>
                                      string(13) "574fff863c2d0"
                                    }
                                  }
                                }
                              }
                            }
```

and if you're asking about log file here is the error log i'm getting: 
[Thu Jun 02 11:11:37.373825 2016] [:error] [pid 5053:tid 140435666220800] [client 91.218.196.212:49810] FastCGI: server "/var/www/clients/client2/web93/cgi-bin/php5-fcgi-*-80-etoolset.dev.artio.pl" stderr: PHP message: PHP Warning:  chdir(): open_basedir restriction in effect. File(/var/www/clients/client2/web93) is not within the allowed path(s): (/var/www/clients/client2/web93/web:/var/www/clients/client2/web93/tmp:/var/www/etoolset.dev.artio.pl/web:/srv/www/etoolset.dev.artio.pl/web:/usr/share/php5:/tmp:/usr/share/php) in /var/www/clients/client2/web93/web/public/chat.php on line 3, referer: http://etoolset.dev.artio.pl/edit/company/dotpay/63

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a spelling mistake with your `Payer` `payment_method`; you have `payapl`.

Comment: Thanks mate.. you know I just waste 2 days at my working debuging